# how to use the Sharepoint:ClientPeoplepicker in html to limit the number of people?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

```
<td class="auto-style8">
 <%--<asp:TextBox ID="txtmanag2" runat="server" Width="200px" MaxLength="50" ToolTip="Alphabets and . are allowed" ></asp:TextBox>--%>
 <SharePoint:ClientPeoplePicker ID="PeoplePicker2" runat="server" VisibleSuggestions="3" Rows="1" AllowMultipleEntities="false" CssClass="ms-long ms-spellcheck-true" Height="85px" Width="185px" />
</td>
<td>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator12" runat="server" ErrorMessage="" ControlToValidate="PeoplePicker2" ValidationGroup="vgbtnsubmit" Enabled="True">
<img src="../../../_layouts/15/images/NAB_Error.png" />
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator> 
 </td>
```

If we tried with this kind of code a text box with the kind giving access to all users 
and also we didnt get any idea of what to change in principal source and principal account type in the properties 
here we want to limit the users so that only particular will be loaded and shown for search
we tried doing with  but the members are 400!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you know who all are those users which you want to populate in peoplepicker, add them to a new SharePoint group. Then you can set the PrincipalType property of control to SPGroup and also set [SharePointGroupID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.clientpeoplepicker.sharepointgroupid.aspx) property to that group's ID